# How to add additional audio track to video player with libvlc

Tags: python, audio, vlc

I'm looking for playing a video with vlc player via python3.8. I'm able to play a movie (mp4) but I would like to add additional audio tracks. I read that the 'add slave' method is the (new) way but I'm not able to use it properly: I'm not able to add subtitles nor audio track.

To summerize: what I want to achieve with Python is roughly the following:
https://wiki.videolan.org/VLC_HowTo/Play_an_external_audio_track_for_a_video

my current (non working) snippet:

```
import vlc

base_path = r"Z:/test/libvlc/"
video_file = base_path + "original.mp4"
audio_file = base_path + "2xlcDLHY7k0-instru+vocal_stereo.wav"
sub_file = base_path + "word.ass"

Instance = vlc.Instance()
player = Instance.media_player_new()
Media = Instance.media_new(video_file)
AdditionalTrack = player.add_slave(player, audio_file, True, i_type="audio")
Sub = player.add_slave(player,sub_file, True)
player.set_media(Media)

while True:
    player.play()
```

I found doc for 'add_slave' func here:
https://www.olivieraubert.net/vlc/python-ctypes/doc/
but I'm not able to use it properly

*libvlc_media_slaves_add(p_md, i_type, i_priority, psz_uri)*
**Add a slave to the current media. A slave is an external input source that may contains an additional subtitle track (like a .srt) or an additional audio track (like a .ac3).**
Parameters: p_md - media descriptor object. i_type - subtitle or audio. i_priority - from 0 (low priority) to 4 (high priority). psz_uri - Uri of the slave (should contain a valid scheme).

If anyone know how to add subtitles or additional audio track,
I would be grateful to him if he can advise me how to,

thanks a lot !

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Z:/midge_play_karaoke-v010.py", line 11, in <module>
    AdditionalTrack = player.add_slave(player, audio_file, True, i_type="audio")
TypeError: add_slave() got multiple values for argument 'i_type'

Comment: I am using: libvlc v3.0.9113

Answer (score 1):

use this code instead.

`AdditionalTrack = player.add_slave(player, audio_file, True, i_type=vlc.MediaSlaveType(1))`

i-type parameter is not a string type.

Comment: Here's what worked for me:  
  
`audio = self.Instance.media_new('test2.mp3').get_mrl()  
self.player.add_slave(1, audio, True)`  
The first parameter (1) is for indicating that it is audio, the second parameter (audio) is the uri for the audio material, and the third parameter (true) is for indicating that the new material should be used right away.  
I found that this code only works when put directly after putting the original video to play.